# How do you connect a PC to a mobile network?

Tags: wireless-networking

Using a SIM card, and a SIM card reader, what other equipment do you need to connect a computer that doesn't have support for cellular connectivity to a cellular network?

My understanding of SIM cards and mobile networks is that they are simply smart cards that only authenticate your access to a mobile network and that the cellular device is what actually facilitates the mobile connection.

Comment: Most people connect a computer to a cellular network using a WiFi mobile hotspot.

Comment: Well, yes, but the "mobile hotspot" is still just a cellular modem regardless of its shape.

Comment: It's a bit unusual to have a SIM card reader not part of a modem. Are you sure you don't actually have a modem that includes that reader?

Comment: You can use USB to share your mobile network with PC. You can refer to: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tethering-use-mobile-internet-pc/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowadays most people use an LTE personal Wi-Fi hotspot, or enable the personal hotspot or tethering feature of their smartphone.

If you don't want a separate device with its own power to manage, then you need a cellular radio card (a.k.a. "wireless modem", "LTE modem", "LTE USB stick" etc. ). You can buy them from Sierra Wireless, Novatel, ZTE, Huawei, and others. They cost as low as $25 US. It's a different radio technology than Wi-Fi or Bluetooth. It's probably best to contact your wireless carrier and ask if they have a preferred USB LTE modem for their network. The modem will have its own SIM card slot.

Comment: Hm... on amazon.com, an LTE USB stick goes for 20-50 US$. Where did you get the $200 figure?

Comment: Also many high-end _Lenovo_ and _Dell_ laptops have LTE build-in modems nowadays. In that case You just need to check where the SIM card slot is.

Comment: It sounds like the question is looking for something even more basic as the machine already has a SIM card reader.

Comment: @sleske Thanks, fixed. I think I was only looking at the longstanding brands I trust and not the recent import brands.

Comment: @kasperd A SIM card is just a smart card variant that the wireless telephony industry adopted, and I've seen people confuse the two before, so I figured OP just had a smart card reader and he didn't realize it had nothing to do with wireless data service.

Comment: @Spiff If one were to build their own LTE connected device from scratch and that card reader could be used in such a setup to access the SIM card, then it is reasonable to call it a SIM card reader. If there however is something fundamentally incompatible between the card reader and a SIM card (such as different layout of the contact points, different voltages, or that the card reader is hardcoded to speak a different protocol from what's used for SIM cards), then it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 4):

You need a mobile hotspot, or a cellular modem.  Both devices connect to a cellular network and need a data plan from that cellular provider.